# <ul> inheriting properties it shouldn't

Tags: css, list, inheritance

I have two pages styled with CSS. The first one has a ul list of images, I gave it a "list-style:none". On the second one I wanted to create a simple text list with pointers (with a list style). I can't however apply any list style to the second list. My code looks like this:

```
page 1
<div id="images">
<ul>
<li>image</li>
...
</ul>
</div>

page 2
<div id="mylist>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
...
</ul>

css

#images ul, ul li {
list-style:none;
}

#mylist ul, ul li {
list-style-type:square;
}
```

But it doesn't work. The list in #mylist still has no pointers. I've inspected the element in my browser and that's what it said: the properties of #images apply to the

  inside #mylist, while #images isn't even used in the file where #mylist is!
  I've tried:

specifying uls as child elements with >

changing the property of #images to "list-style-type:none"

resetting the style of #mylist ul with "list-style:0;"

Other properties of #mylist ul apply normally (like margins, padding, colors, font size etc.), only this one seems to be unchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#images ul, ul li {
list-style:none;
}

#mylist ul, ul li {
list-style-type:square;
}
```

Both of these apply to just `ul li`, which is probably not what you want. Don’t even bother selecting the `li`s.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
    #mylist ul li, ul li {
list-style-type:square;
}
```

or

```
#mylist ul, ul  {
list-style:square;
}
```